# Fedora 22: Packet Tracer doesn't work..!

Tags: linux, fedora

I Installed Cisco Packet Tracer on my Fedora 22, but it could not launch.
I had run this to install it

```
# sudo ./PacketTracer533_i386_no_tutorials_installer-rpm.bin
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: Nothing happening when I lunch it, nothing outcomes

Comment: can you try running strace on the packet tracer at run time and record the output?  or at least an exit value for the application?

Comment: Sorry, can u explain plz?

Answer (score 0):

After you download packet tracer, run the following commands:

```
cd /to/the/location/of/the/Packet/Tracer/file
tar -xvzf PT601LinuxNoTutorial
cd ./PacketTracer<version>
bash ./install
```

You should also pay attention if you have a 32 or 64bit operating system.
However, you can install 32bit packet tracer on 64bit OS, but you'll need i386 architecture on your fedora

Link to the latest version:
http://myitzn.blogspot.fr/2015/02/free-download-cisco-packet-tracer-62_7.html

Comment: I installed it but it could not run, when I type packettracer it's outcome Starting Packet Tracer 6.2
But nothing happening.. I don't know what is the problem..

Comment: before typing packettracer on the comand line, you should first add it to the path variable on fedora's system.

Comment: when I type it I get as Outcome of command this Message "Starting Packet Tracer 6.2"